# freetds connection issue macOS

Tags: sql-server, macos, freetds

I am trying to connect to a remote MSSQL DB from a MacOS.

I am able to connect to the remote DB using freetds

```
tsql -H servername.database.windows.net -U username -P password -D database_name -p 1433
```

But as I make an entry in the `/usr/local/etc/freetds.conf` file with following settings

```
[dbservername]
    host = servername.database.windows.net
    port = 1433
    database = database_name
    tds version = 7.3
```

And try to connect using

```
tsql -S dbservername -U username -P password
```

I get the following error

```
locale is "C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
 2Msg 40532 (severity 20, state 1) from dbservername:
    "Cannot open server "dbservername" requested by the login.  The login failed."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

tsql -C output

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                        Version: freetds v1.00.48
         freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/1.00.48/etc
 MS db-lib source compatibility: no
    Sybase binary compatibility: no
                  Thread safety: yes
                  iconv library: yes
                    TDS version: 7.3
                          iODBC: no
                       unixodbc: no
          SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                       Kerberos: no
                        OpenSSL: yes
                         GnuTLS: no
                           MARS: no
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Have you ever figured out how to solve this @anonR ?

Comment: No, I didn't. I was able to get everything working in Linux though after this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `FreeTDS` is looking for your configuration file in a different directory. `tsql -C` shows that it is expecting the file to be in `/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/1.00.48/etc`.

Move `freetds.conf` from `/usr/local/etc/` to `/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/1.00.48/etc` and give it a try again. Good luck!

Comment: As soon as I edit the configuration file in /usr/local/etc/ the changes are reflected to the one in /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/1.00.48/etc automatically.
So that would not solve the issue there.

Comment: Ah, you must have a symlink set up. I'll review further.

Comment: I installed via HomeBrew, So it would have made the symlink for same.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to answer, but it's required to write the username as:

```
username@servername
```

when connected to Azure Database (sqlserver in Azure)